# basis closed, bounded

Tags: real-analysis

This is Exercise 3 from p. 39 of Munkres: [Analysis on Manifolds](http://books.google.com/books?id=logpAQAAMAAJ)

Let $\mathbb R^\infty$ be the set of all "infinite-tuples" $x = (x_1, x_2,  \ldots  )$ of real numbers that end in an infinite string of $0$s. (See the exercises of § 1.)

Define an inner product on $\mathbb R^\infty$ by the rule $\langle x, y\rangle =
\sum x_iy_i$. (This is a finite sum, since all but finitely many terms vanish.) Let $\|x - y\|$ be the corresponding metric on
$\mathbb R^\infty$. Define
$$e_i = (0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots);$$ 
where 1 appears in the i-th place. Then the $e_i$ form a basis for $\mathbb R^\infty$.

Let $X$ be the set of all the points $e_i$.
Show that $X$ is closed, bounded, and non-compact.

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy to show, that if $i\ne j$ then $\|e_i-e_j\|=\sqrt2$. Using this fact you can show easily if a sequence of points from $X$ is convergent, then it is eventually constant. Indeed, let $(x_i)$ be a convergent sequence of points of $X$. Then it is Cauchy, i.e. there is $N$ such that $p,q>N$ implies $\|x_p-x_q\|<\sqrt{2}$. This clearly implies that all values $x_p$ for $p>N$ must be the same.

The above fact should help you to show the closedness. (A subset $X$ of a metric space is closed if and only if for every convergent sequence of points of $X$ the limit belongs to $X$ as well, see e.g. [proofwiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Closure_of_Subset_of_Metric_Space_by_Convergent_Sequence).)

A different approach: You could try to show that the complement $\mathbb R^\infty\setminus X$ is open. Hint: Start by showing that for $x_0\notin X$ the neighborhood $U(x_0;\frac{\sqrt2}2)$ contains at most one point of $X$.

Boundedness is easy. Just notice that $\|e_i\|=1$. I.e. we have $\|x\|\le 1$ for each $x\in X$. (Definition of boundedness is that $X$ is bounded if and only if there exists an $M$ such that $\|x\|\le M$ for each $x\in X$.)

If a metric space is compact, then every sequence has a convergent subsequence. Again the fact that $\|e_i-e_j\|=\sqrt2$ should suffice you to show that $(e_i)$ has no convergent subsequence. (Recall that every convergent sequence is Cauchy, see e.g. [proofwiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Convergent_Sequence_is_Cauchy_Sequence).)

Comment: Can you please walk me through the steps, I'm not seeing how boundedness is "easy". All I note is that the norm of e sub i = 1 for all i, so is that all we can say for boundedness?

Comment: What you wrote is sufficient for boundedness. (I've added the part about boundedness to my post.)

Comment: For closedness, can you elaborate on your argument? I'm not sure that I have the idea down

Comment: I've added more details. Of course, you could also try other approach to show $X$ is closed. (There are many ways to do this.)

Comment: How do you use the fact fact that you can show easily if a sequence of points from X  is convergent, then it is eventually constant? I am just going to say, by the fact that all Cauchy sequences are closed and bounded. Is this sufficient?

Comment: I am not sure how you want to show it using that *all Cauchy sequences are closed and bounded*. (But I do not claim that such proof is not possible.) I've added my proof to the post.

Comment: @Buddy: What do you mean by sequences being closed? That the set $\{x_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is closed, or? And how does that relate to the set itself being closed?